# Automatically evaluating related cells

Tags: dynamic, evaluation

I have the cells:

```
In[1]:= l = 2 + 2;

In[2]:= l >= 5
```

After evaluating them:

```
Out[2]:= False
```

Is there a way to evaluate all related cells, so if I change `In[1]` to `l = 2 + 5`, `Out[2]` would become `True` without evaluating the whole notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something along these lines could help?

```
$PrePrint= # /. 
         Except[Null] :> With[{line = $Line}, DynamicSetting@Dynamic@In[line]] /. 
    DownValues[In] &;
```

After running this, everything you evaluate is automatically wrapped in `Dynamic` so its value is updated automatically. I haven't tested it much so there may be issues.

(Be careful with endless dynamic updating loops)

Answer (score 3):

You can try `Dynamic`(by the way, `l = 2 + 5` won't make `l >= 5` to be `False`…):

```
In[20]:= l = 1 + 3

Out[20]= 4

In[19]:= Dynamic[l >= 5]

Out[19]= False
```

Comment: I've fixed about comparison, and is their a way to do this for all cell, without wrapping in `Dynamic` explicitly?

Comment: @m0nhawk No other easy way. You either tell each related cell to listen to a dynamic value by wrapping their contents in `Dynamic` OR you re-evaluate these cells. You can play with cell options, but *Mathematica* will never figure out on its own which cells it should update and which cells it shouldn't.

Comment: @m0nhawk Just as what István Zachar has pointed out. (At least I failed to find one 囧. )